Getting 'uncommitted work pending' even after putting in a queuable class
Getting 'You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out' error even after making the callout in a queuable class. Below the essence of the logic
QueuableDummyclass.cls
  public with sharing class QueuableDummyclass implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{
    public List<String> masterDataSelected;

    public QueuableDummyclass(List<String> selectedInput) {
        this.selectedInput = selectedInput;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        //HTTP Callouts
        Http http = new Http(); 
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(); 
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        request.setBody(selectedInput);
        ......
        ......
        response = http.send(request);

        //DML Operation

         if(selectedInput[0] == '<something>'){

             Boolean dataInserted_1 = insertData_1(response.getBody());
             if(dataInserted_1){
              selectedInput.remove(0);
             }
            
          }else if(selectedInput[0] == '<something else>'){

             Boolean dataInserted_2 = insertData_2(response.getBody());
             if(dataInserted_2){
              selectedInput.remove(0);
             }
          }
         
            
            Integer delayInMinutes = 1;
                   
            if(!selectedInput.isEmpty()){
                System.enqueueJob(new QueuableDummyclass(selectedInput), delayInMinutes);
             }
    }



    public static Boolean insertData_1(String input){

      Savepoint savePoint=null;

      try{

            savePoint = Database.setSavepoint();
           //Insert Object 'A' record based on input

           // Update Object 'B' record based on input

       }catch (DMLException e){
 
          if(savePoint != null)
               Database.rollback(savePoint);
           
           return false;
      
       }

    }



    public static Boolean insertData_2(String input){

      Savepoint savePoint=null;

      try{

             savePoint = Database.setSavepoint();
           //Insert Object 'C' record based on input

           // Update Object 'D' record based on input

       }catch (DMLException e){
 
          if(savePoint != null)
               Database.rollback(savePoint);
           
           return false;
      
       }

    }
}

The DML operation is done after the Callout and once Queued, the 2nd set should run as a different transaction, which should not cause this error. What am I missing?

Your shortening/anonimization of the code may have masked the issue here. Are you performing your callout in a loop? How is your queueable class getting executed initially? Are you doing something like new QueuableDummyclass().execute(null);?

This particular class gets executed as 'System.enqueueJob(new QueuableDummyclass(selectedInput));'
And NO. I ma not making the callouts in a loop.

Are you enqueuing anything else in QueuableDummyclass before http.send(request);? Or scheduling a batch job? or calling Database.setSavepoint();? All of those also count as "DML" for purposes of making a callout.

Now that you mentioned it, I am using Database.setSavepoint(). I have updated the code to reflect much of my work.

I am not enqueuing anything else other than this 1 class.

Solved. Mistake from my end. There was a DML operation getting triggered which didn't get my attention.
